# How to make a DELETE action with redux-observable?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, axios, redux-observable

I'm implementing a Dialog that ask the user if he wants to delete an Item from a DataTable, If he agrees, an epic should send a DELETE request to the backend and then update the state of the DataTable to show the list of items without the deleted one. My problem is with the epic, when I dispatch the OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG action, that opens modal dialog, redux-observable starts executing the DELETE_DATA action and sends a stream of DELETE requests to the backend, even without clicking the AGREE option that should dispatch the DELETE_DATA action.
The epic should only send the DELETE request when the user dispatches the DELETE_DATA action, how can I achieve that?

This is the my DIALOG Component (in this case it deletes a Role):

```
class DeleteDialog extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <MenuItem onClick={_ => {
                console.log(`Edit ${JSON.stringify(this.props.item)}`)
                this.props.openDeleteDialog(this.props.item)
            }}>
            <IconButton aria-label="Edit">
                <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography>
                Delete
            </Typography>
            </MenuItem>
            <Dialog open={this.props.open} onRequestClose={this.props.cancelDeleteData}>
            <DialogTitle>{"Delete Alert"}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>
                Are you sure you want to delete: {this.props.item.name}
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.props.cancelDeleteData} color="primary">
                Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.props.deleteData(this.props.item)} color="primary">
                Agree
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  open: state.role.delete.open,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  ...deleteDispatchesForScope(scopes.ROLE, dispatch)
})
```

This is my action Creator, it is generic so scope can be USERS, ROLES and so on:

```
export const actionTypes = {
    OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG: 'OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG',
    DELETE_DATA: 'DELETE_DATA',
    CANCEL_DELETE_DATA: 'CANCEL_DELETE_DATA'
}

export const deleteActionTypesForScope = scope => ({
    OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG: `${scope}_${actionTypes.OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG}`,
    DELETE_DATA: `${scope}_${actionTypes.DELETE_DATA}`,
    CANCEL_DELETE_DATA: `${scope}_${actionTypes.CANCEL_DELETE_DATA}`
})

export const deleteActionForScope = scope => {
    const actionTypes = deleteActionTypesForScope(scope);
    return {
        openDeleteDialog: item => ({
            type: actionTypes.OPEN_DELETE_DIALOG,
            item: item,
            open: true
        }),
        deleteData: item => ({
            type: actionTypes.DELETE_DATA,
            item: item,
            open: false
        }),
        cancelDeleteData: _ => ({
            type: actionTypes.CANCEL_DELETE_DATA,
            item: {},
            open: false
        })
    }
}

export const deleteDispatchesForScope = (scope, dispatch) => {
    const actionCreators = deleteActionForScope(scope);
    return {
        openDeleteDialog: item => dispatch(actionCreators.openDeleteDialog(item)),
        deleteData: item => dispatch(actionCreators.deleteData(item)),
        cancelDeleteData: _ => dispatch(actionCreators.cancelDeleteData())
    }
}
```

And my EPIC is this:

```
const deleteRolEpic = (action$, store) => (
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.DELETE_DATA)
        .filter(_ => !store.getState().rol.delete.loading)
        .switchMap(action => {
            let rolpath = 'roles/' + action.item.id;
            return Observable.fromPromise(axios.delete(rolpath))
                .map(response => {
                    history.push('/roles');
                })
        })
)
```

Where history redirects to the path where is my DataTable of roles, in this case. Also, I'm using Axios to send my requests to the backend.
The error I get is this:

```
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ proxyConsole.js:56
printWarning @ warning.js:35
warning @ warning.js:59
getInternalInstanceReadyForUpdate @ ReactUpdateQueue.js:54
enqueueSetState @ ReactUpdateQueue.js:209
./node_modules/react/lib/ReactBaseClasses.js.ReactComponent.setState @ ReactBaseClasses.js:64
onStateChange @ connectAdvanced.js:205
notify @ Subscription.js:26
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:65
onStateChange @ connectAdvanced.js:202
dispatch @ createStore.js:173
dispatch @ VM4042:2
(anonymous) @ createEpicMiddleware.js:59
dispatch @ VM4042:2
deleteData @ delete-actions.js:38
render @ RolDeleteDialog.js:54
(anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:795
measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:75
_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:794
_renderValidatedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:821
_updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:745
_performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:723
updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:644
receiveComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:546
receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:124
_updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:753
_performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:723
updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:644
performUpdateIfNecessary @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:560
performUpdateIfNecessary @ ReactReconciler.js:156
runBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:150
perform @ Transaction.js:143
perform @ Transaction.js:143
perform @ ReactUpdates.js:89
flushBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:172
closeAll @ Transaction.js:209
perform @ Transaction.js:156
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `ButtonBase`, expected `function`.
    in ButtonBase (created by withStyles(ButtonBase))
    in withStyles(ButtonBase) (created by Button)
    in Button (created by withStyles(Button))
    in withStyles(Button) (at RolDeleteDialog.js:54)
    in div (created by DialogActions)
    in div (created by DialogActions)
    in DialogActions (created by withStyles(DialogActions))
    in withStyles(DialogActions) (at RolDeleteDialog.js:50)
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by withStyles(Paper))
    in withStyles(Paper) (created by Dialog)
    in Transition (created by Fade)
    in Fade (created by withTheme(Fade))
    in withTheme(Fade) (created by Dialog)
    in div (created by Modal)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ proxyConsole.js:56
printWarning @ warning.js:35
warning @ warning.js:59
checkReactTypeSpec @ checkReactTypeSpec.js:80
validatePropTypes @ ReactElementValidator.js:162
createElement @ ReactElementValidator.js:216
createEagerElementUtil @ createEagerElementUtil.js:31
(anonymous) @ createEagerFactory.js:18
render @ withStyles.js:345
(anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:795
measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:75
_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:794
_renderValidatedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:821
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:361
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js:236
_createInitialChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js:703
mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js:522
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js:236
_createInitialChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js:703
mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js:522
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js:236
_createInitialChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js:703
mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js:522
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js:236
_createInitialChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js:703
mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js:522
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
performInitialMount @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:370
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:257
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:104
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:126
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
_renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js:319
_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:401
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:342
renderLayer @ Portal.js:130
componentDidMount @ Portal.js:70
(anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:264
measureLifeCyclePerf @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:75
(anonymous) @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:263
notifyAll @ CallbackQueue.js:76
close @ ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80
closeAll @ Transaction.js:209
perform @ Transaction.js:156
perform @ Transaction.js:143
perform @ ReactUpdates.js:89
flushBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:172
closeAll @ Transaction.js:209
perform @ Transaction.js:156
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js:147
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at Object.putListener (EventPluginHub.js:132)
    at Object.putListener (ReactDOMComponent.js:177)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
    at Object.renderSubtreeIntoContainer [as unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer] (ReactMount.js:342)
    at Portal.renderLayer (Portal.js:130)
    at Portal.componentDidMount (Portal.js:70)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:264
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:263
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.deleteData(this.props.item)} color="primary">
  Agree
</Button>
```

To:

```
<Button onClick={ e => this.props.deleteData(this.props.item)} color="primary">
  Agree
</Button>
```

Else you will dispatch "deleteData" each time the component renders.